# Blackjack Program for C++. How can I add multiple char values in the switch statements?

Tags: c++

Write a program that scores a blackjack hand. In blackjack, a player receives from two to five cards. (The player decides how many, but that has no effect on this exercise.) The cards 2 through 10 are scored as 2 through 10 points each. The face cards, jack, queen, and king are scored as 10 points. The goal is to come as close to a score of 21 as possible without going over 21. Hence, any score over 21 is called "busted." The ace can count as either 1 or 11, whichever is better for the user. For example, an ace and a 10 can be scored as either 11 or 21. Since 21 is a better score, this hand is scored as 21. An ace and two 8' s can be scored as either 17 or 27. Since 27 is a "busted" score, this hand is scored as 17.
The user is asked how many cards she or he has, and the user responds with one of the integers 2, 3, 4, or 5. The user is then asked for the card values.
Card values are 2 through 10, jack, queen, king, and ace. A good way to handle input is to use the type char so that the card input 2, for example, is read as the character '2', rather than as the number 2. Input the values 2 through 9 as the characters '2' through '9'. Input the values 10, jack, queen, king, and ace as the characters 't ', 'j', 'q', 'k', and 'a'. An ace can also be entered as a '1'. Be sure to allow upper as well as lowercase letters as input.
  After reading in the values, the program should convert them from character values to numeric card scores, taking special care for aces. The output is either a number between 2 and 21 (inclusive) or the word Busted. Use functions where appropriate. Use a switch statement to determine the correct value for a card. Your program should include a loop that lets the user repeat this calculation until the user says she or he is done.

**Example Output:**
Enter the number of cards: 3
Enter cards: a78
The value of your hand is 16.

Would you like to score another hand (Y or N)?: y
Enter the number of cards: 4
Enter cards: 354K
You are BUSTED!

I'm stuck on adding the values of the cards.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int cards_in_hand;
int value, total_value = 0;
std::string card_value;


cout << "Enter the number of cards: ";
cin >> cards_in_hand;


cout << "Enter cards: ";
cin >> card_value;


for (int i = 0; i < card_value.size(); i++)
{

    switch (card_value[i])
    {
    case'2':
        value = 2;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case '3':
        value = 3;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case '4':
        value = 4;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case '5':
        value = 5;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case '6':
        value = 6;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case '7': {
        value = 7;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break; }
    case '8': {
        value = 8;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break; }

    case '9':
        value = 9;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case 't':
    case 'T':
    case 'j':
    case 'J':
    case 'q':
    case 'Q':
    case 'k':
    case 'K':
        value = 10;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case 'a':
    case 'A': {
        if (total_value <= 10)
        {
            value = 11;
        }
        else
        {
            value = 1;
        }
        total_value = total_value + value;
    }

        if (total_value <= 21)
        {
            cout << "The value of your hand is: " << total_value << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "YOU ARE BUSTED!\n";
    }


}
```

When I enter a78 for cards, it works only for the first char I enter, which is 'a'. It returns only 11, but how do I make it add the 7 and 8 to get 16?
How do I add the 7 and 8 first?

How can I make the cin input take the three values such as a78, then add them together in the switch statement? So that it adds 7 + 8 + a which should be 1, to equal 16?

Comment: Advice -- Consider a `std::map<char, int>` to obtain the value instead of one gigantic switch statement.  That would eliminate all of the redundant code you have now.

Comment: Thank you but the assignment says that I have to "use a switch statement to determine the correct value for a card."

Comment: Can you encase the switch statement in a loop to count through the cards? Set total_value to 0 first, then run a for loop to iterate through the three cards getting the values (maybe a character array?) and processing through the switch statement each time, adding the results as it goes?

Comment: Write a loop for each character in the input string.  You're trying to take the entire input string and use it in the switch, which is wrong.  You want to switch on each character.

Comment: I just added a for loop, but it's only looping the value for a, not 7 and 8? How do I make it add the values for 7 and 8?

Comment: @Jessica *I just added a for loop, but it's only looping the value for a,*  -- Well obviously your loop is wrong.  It should be very simple to write a loop that goes through each character in an array or string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How can i accomplish that? may you please review my code? Why isnt the for loop working? It only goes through the 'a' char

Comment: @Jessica That `for` loop does not go through the `card_value` string.  I think you need to understand the logic first before writing more code.  You want to loop through "a78", not any other value.  Also, arrays in C++ start from 0, not 1.

Comment: @Jessica are you using an array for your cards? You can iterate through the cards while using the counter in the loop to iterate through each character in the array and do the work with the switch statement. Is that how you are doing it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how do I make it loop through a78?

Comment: @David Peterson Harvey how do i write the array in the code?

Comment: @Jessica -- So you don't know how to iterate through each character in a string?  Maybe you should write smaller programs first to familiarize yourself in how to loop through a string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but is it achievable with my code (chars and switch statements) and a for loop, or do I need to start all over again?

Comment: @Jessica declare char card_value[5] outside the for loop, then iterate through your count, getting the input for each one within the for loop. You'll be inputting each answer separately, adding to total_value, which was declared and initialized to 0 outside the loop. Instead of card_value, you'll evaluate card_value[n] with each iteration.

Comment: @Jessica First, declare `card_value` as a `std::string`, not a single char.  Read the "a78" into that string variable.  Then it is as simple as `for (int i = 0; i < card_value.size(); ++i) { ... switch(card_value[i]) { ...` adding to the total each iteration.

Comment: Also, start the count at n=0 and go to 4, so you don't waste an array value, or evaluate card_value[n-1] to do the same. The first way is cleaner.

Comment: @David Peterson Harvey Thank you. I added [3] at the end of every card_value variable in my code, but it still adds only the a char?? what modifications do I need to make?

Comment: @Jessica Also, you could collapse the 't','J',"Q',and ;'K' cases into one, as they all do the same thing.  `case 't':case 'T':case'J':case 'j':case 'Q':case'q':case'K':case 'k':...`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie has the better, more C++ like way, if you've dealt with strings already. I'm coming from C (literally been working in it for several hours) so I'm not thinking C++. Both will work but his is cleaner. You need to think through the logic and flow so you can see what's happening in order to get it right. Take your time.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you so much. I edited the code in the thread and it is working, and correctly shows the value of 7 and 8, but it wont add the numbers all together. Is the code for total_value = total_value + value; wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to remove some of the bugs from your code (mentioned it in comments),but still in order to get expected output you  need to do some extra computation.So you might want to use greedy approach to find maximum total value you can get .
So for input
number of cards : 4
card value : a666
Your code will give ouput "YOU ARE BUSTED !"
but correct output is >
The value of your hand is: 19
The reason is for first 'a' you will directly add 11 to total without looking ahead into the string.So in order to avoid that first go through all cards in the string ,if you found an 'a' don't do anything(do not add 1 or 11 to total_value) just increment count of 'a' that you have seen before , if it's not an 'a' then add value of card  directly to total value because there is no way around(You must add them). Now at the end go through all the 'a' and check how many of them can be converted into 11s without getting busted. (See code,its too easy !!!)
Now try combining two code fragments you will get what you want.

```
int value, total_value = 0;
string card_value;  //card_value should be string

cout << "Enter the number of cards: ";
cin >> cards_in_hand;


cout << "Enter cards: ";
cin >> card_value;

//Strings are 0 based indexed,so n must be initially 0
for (int n = 0; n < cards_in_hand; n++)
{

    switch (card_value[n])
    {
    case'2':
        value = 2;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case '3':
        value = 3;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case '4':
        value = 4;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case '5':
        value = 5;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case '6':
        value = 6;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case '7':
        value = 7;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case '8':
        value = 8;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;

    case '9':
        value = 9;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case 't':
    case 'T':
        value = 10;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;

    case 'j':
    case 'J':
        value = 10;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case 'q':
    case 'Q':
        value = 10;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case 'k':
    case 'K':
        value = 10;
        total_value = value + total_value;
        break;
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
        if (total_value <= 10)
        {
            value = 11;
        }
        else
        {
            value = 1;
        }
        total_value = total_value + value;
       // n++; remove this line as you are doing already incrementing in loop statement
    }


}

if (total_value <= 21)
{
    cout << "The value of your hand is: " << total_value << endl;
}
else
    cout << "YOU ARE BUSTED!\n";
```

Here is the code for converting remaining 'a's into 11s and 1s.

```
//This variable stores how much value you can get only from 'a's without exceeding 21
int max_from_a = 0;

//If all 'a's are converted into 1 and still value goes above 21 then  "YOU ARE BUSTED !"
if(total_value + a_cnt > 21)
{
    cout<<"YOU ARE BUSTED !\n";
    return 0;
}

//Finding max_from_a
for(int used = 1 ; used <= a_cnt ; used++)
{

  //convert 'used' number of 'a's into 11 and remaining 'a's into 1
  int from_used = 11*used + 1*(a_cnt - used);

  //You'll get this....
  if(total_value + from_used > 21)
    break;

  max_from_a = max (max_from_a , from_used);

}

//Add value of a's into total_value
total_value = total_value + max_from_a;

cout << "The value of your hand is: " << total_value << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you. What are the "a_cnt", "used", "max", and "from_used" variables? I get errors when I try to use them in my code.

Comment: What does it stand for?

Comment: What does "max" mean? in  max_from_a = max (max_from_a , from_used);

Comment: a_cnt -> number of 'a's or 'A's

Comment: used is number of 'a's which get converted to 11 and other 'a's will be 1 , max(a,b) is function which returns maximum value among a and b ,  "from_used" is the value that you get after converting "used" number of "a"s into 11 and remaining "a"s into 1. Hope that helps

Comment: I would go to `case '2': case '3': .... case '9': value = card_value[n] - '0'; break`.  Then in the 'a' case, set `value` to zero, and then increment the `total_value` *outside* the switch.  This reduces the amount of  code quite a bit.  An additional improvement, might be to set `value` to 1 in the ace case (as well as counting how many aces there are).  If there is an ace, you can then add another 10 if that doesn't bust you, or 20 if there were at least two aces.  (You never have to consider adding 30 as that *must* break you.)